# Seaborn jointplot with defined axes limits

Tags: python, seaborn

I am trying to generate some figures using the joint plot command of Seaborn. I have a list of tuples called "data", with the coordinates (x,y) that needed to be plotted. The x-coordinates are in range (200,1400) and the y-coordinates are in range (300,900). However, I need to show the entire region I am working, demonstrating the concentration of the points. I need the x-coordinate to be in range (0,3000) and the y-coordinate to be in range (0-1200), and I am failing to do so.

Here is my code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

np.shape(y)
xx = np.linspace(0,1080,np.shape(y))
yy = np.linspace(0,1920,np.shape(y))

sns.jointplot(xx="x", yy="y", data=data, kind="kde")
```

I returns the error: "TypeError: jointplot() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'x' and 'y'".

If I don't use the xx and yy variables, it gives the plot with the axes limited automatically.

[image]

How can I set the axes to the ranges I need?

Comment: `sns.jointplot(x=xx, y=yy, data=data, kind="kde")`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can plot your data and modify the plot's axis limits later:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate some random date
x = np.random.normal(loc=650, scale=100, size=1000)
y = np.random.normal(loc=600, scale=200, size=1000)

plot = sns.jointplot(x, y, kind="kde")
plot.ax_marg_x.set_xlim(0, 3000)
plot.ax_marg_y.set_ylim(0, 1200)

plt.show()
```

Comment: it seems like it cuts off the limits after the subplots are produced, making some remaining peaks very small (in other words, not normalized/scaled). Is there a clean way to actually have it prune that data (rather than doing it manually before the call to `jointplot`) and then recompute/redraw?

Comment: A plotting function is usually intended for plotting the given data, not cleaning/pruning it. I think your question is better suited as a new question than a comment on this answer to another question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xlim` and `ylim` params:

```
plot = sns.jointplot(x, y, kind="kde", xlim=(200, 1400), ylim=(300, 900))
```